How events are handled by node.js
I just started to learn node.js and i am not much aware about how node.js handle events. i encountered with an issue while playing with events handlers(calling same event multiple times) and  getting unexpected behaviour.
here is the issue,
i have created a text file named userlist.txt with and empty array and i am trying to add the user in userlist.txt file whenever user login. i was expecting a result like this:- ["jhon", "smith", "jos", "test"] but ending up with result like this:- ["Test"]] or ["Jos"]]], need help to understand this behaviour and how events are handled by node.js
Code reference, getting this output although output is not stable
here is the code:-
const fs = require('fs');
const EventEmmiter = require('events');
const login = new EventEmmiter();

login.on("login",async(username)=>{
    try {
        const userList = await fs.promises.readFile("./userlist.txt", 'utf-8');
        const parsedUserList = JSON.parse(userList);
        parsedUserList.push(username);
        await fs.promises.writeFile("./userlist.txt", JSON.stringify(parsedUserList))
        
        console.log(`user logged in successfully... ${username}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})

login.emit("login", "Jhon");    
login.emit("login", "Smith");
login.emit("login", "Jos");
login.emit("login", "Test");


try using fs.readFileSync and fs.writeFileSync instead.. your code is not waiting for each operation to complete before the next event handler fires.  ["Jos"]]] isn't valid json either and that's because the write operations just mix up

@DiegoD That won't help with the lost write condition of one invocation reading a file, another writing into it, and the first invocation having parsed an old version of the data, updating it, etc.

@AKX before posting I tried myself on nodejs and to make sure the instruction pointer was flowing as expected I put breakpoints inside the login event handler and each of the login.emit calls. The instruction sequence is correctly respected. The second emit call won't be performed before the first call was completed so the next read will follow the previous write. But at condition that the *Sync variants are used. The output file is as expected at the end of the script execution

@DiegoD Well yes, if both IO calls are sync, then that serializes the whole thing, but also stalls the entire Node.js process.

This isn't really about EventEmitter – you have a classic race condition that you can reproduce with just an async function login(name) {}.
The event handler invocations are suspended when you're doing async IO (reading and writing files), so other invocations of the same handler get a different view of the data, and will also conflict with one another writing the data (e.g. you'll lose writes).
Worst case, you'll even have one handler which reads an empty file (since a writeFile call will have opened the file in a truncating mode but may not have had time to write into it), and then JSON.parse() will fail, reading an empty string.
You would need to lock the file around every operation on it if you really do need to read and write full JSON files (which will mean that it will be a bottleneck, since only one concurrent call can ever be doing anything with that data). Using synchronous calls as suggested by Diego in the comments will have a similar effect, but at the expense of entirely stalling the Node process, which is generally undesirable.
A better option might be using an appendFile call with an NDJSON style file (IOW, you wouldn't read the file at all in order to append a new thing to it), but I can't find definitive information on whether appendFile is guaranteed to be atomic either.
An even better option is an actual database, e.g. SQLite, which can natively do atomic operations like these and you don't need to worry about the details (as much).
